# thread_local at block scope

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-local-storage

What is the use of a `thread_local` variable at block scope?

If a compilable sample helps to illustrate the question, here it is:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

namespace My {
    void f(int *const p) {++*p;}
}

int main()
{
    thread_local int n {42};
    std::thread t(My::f, &n);
    t.join();
    std::cout << n << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `43`

In the sample, the new thread gets its own `n` but (as far as I know) can do nothing interesting with it, so why bother? Does the new thread's own `n` have any use? And if it has no use, then what is the point?

Naturally, I assume that there *is* a point. I just do not know what the point might be. This is why I ask.

If the new thread's own `n` wants (as I suppose) special handling by the CPU at runtime—perhaps because, at the machine-code level, one cannot access the own `n` in the normal way via a precalculated offset from the base pointer of the new thread's stack—then are we not merely wasting machine cycles and electricity for no gain? And yet even if special handling were not required, still no gain! Not that I can see.

So why `thread_local` at block scope, please?

**References**

- Cppreference on [`thread_local` and other storage classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)
- An earlier question: [when exactly is a thread_local variable declared at global scope initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35508133/1275653)
- Another earlier question: [thread_local variables initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43424789/1275653)
- Yet another earlier question: [the cost of thread_local](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8489819/1275653)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find `thread_local` is only useful in three cases:

1. If you need each thread to have a unique resource so that they don't have to share, mutex, etc. for using said resource. And even so, this is only useful if the resource is large and/or expensive to create or needs to persist across function invocations (i.e. a local variable inside the function will not suffice).
2. An offshoot of (1) - you may need special logic to run when a calling thread eventually terminates. For this, you can use the destructor of the `thread_local` object created in the function. The destructor of such a `thread_local` object is called once for each thread that entered the code block with the `thread_local` declaration (at the end of the thread's lifetime).
3. You may need some other logic to be performed for each unique thread that calls it, but only once. For instance, you could write a function that registers each unique thread that called a function. This may sound bizarre, but I've found uses for this in managing garbage-collected resources in a library I'm developing. This usage is closely-related to (1) but doesn't get used after its construction. Effectively a sentry object for a thread's entire lifetime.

Comment: Your answer shows expertise. It is illuminating. It is appreciated. It has lent me a perspective I did not have, +1, but are not all three of your cases satisfied by a `thread_local` object at *namespace* scope? If you know of any uses of `thread_local` objects at *block* scope, I would be interested to read of those, too.

Comment: @thb Of course. If you put it at namespace scope all created threads will instantiate it, which could hurt performance. If you put it at block scope it is instantiated exactly once by each thread on the first time control enters that scope. i.e. you don't create anything you don't use.

Comment: Isn't that interesting? Do you happen to know where a object like that is kept? That is, do you know in which linker segment (if that is the correct term) its storage exists? It is not obvious to me that it were possible to keep such an object on the thread's stack; for, if it were kept there, I do not know how executing code would ever find the object.

Comment: (Feel free to ignore the last comment. Obviously, I can experiment with my compiler, myself, and examine the object file it produces. I was only curious in case you had anything interesting to add.)

Comment: @thb Typically `thread_local` objects are allocated on the heap (so no linker involvement). However the compiler ensures that destructors are called for them and resources are cleaned up.

Comment: Awesome answers, much better than I deserve. I am looking for the +99 upvote switch on my screen but cannot find it. I see that you do not have a lot of time available to answer questions on Stack Overflow, so I am glad that you have been available to answer my question yesterday and today.

Answer (score 3):

`static thread_local` and `thread_local` at block scope are equivalent; `thread_local` has a thread storage duration, not static or automatic; therefore, static and automatic specifiers i.e. `thread_local`, which is `auto thread_local`, and `static thread_local` have no effect on the storage duration; semantically, they are nonsense to use and they're just implicitly taken to mean thread storage duration, due to the presence of `thread_local`; static doesn't even modify the linkage at block scope either (because it's always no linkage), so it has no other definition other than modifying storage duration. `extern thread_local` is also possible in block scope. `static thread_local` at file scope gives the `thread_local` variable internal linkage, which means there will be one copy per translation unit in the TLS (each translation unit will resolve to its own variable at the TLS index for the `.exe`, because the assembler will insert the variable in the `rdata$t` section of the `.o` file and mark it in the symbol table as a local symbol due to the lack of the `.global` directive on the symbol). `extern thread_local` at file scope is legal like it is at block scope and uses the `thread_local` copy defined in another translation unit. `thread_local` at file scope is not implicitly static, because it can provide a global symbol definition for another translation unit, which cannot be done by a block-scope variable.

The compiler will store all initialised `thread_local` variables in `.tdata` (including block-scope ones) for ELF and uninitialised ones in `.tbss` for ELF, or all in `.tls` for PE format. I presume the thread library, when creating a thread, will access the `.tls` segment and perform windows API calls (`TlsAlloc` and `TlsSetValue`), which allocate the variables for each `.exe` and `.dll` on the heap and places a pointers in the TLS array of the thread's TEB in the GS segment and returns the index allocated, as well as call `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` routines for dynamic libraries. Presumably, a pointer to a value in the space defined by `_tls_start` and `_tls_end` is what's passed to `TlsSetValue` as the value pointer.

The difference between file scope `static/extern thread_local` and block scope `(extern) thread_local` is the same general difference between file scope `static/extern` and block scope `static/extern`, in that the block scope `thread_local` variable will go out of scope at the end of the function it is defined in, although it can still be returned and accessed by address because of the thread storage duration.

The compiler knows the index of the data in the .tls segment, so it can substitute accesses the GS segment directly, as can be seen on godbolt.

**MSVC**

```
thread_local int a = 5;

int square(int num) {
thread_local int i = 5;
    return a * i;
}
```

```
_TLS    SEGMENT
int a DD        05H                           ; a
_TLS    ENDS
_TLS    SEGMENT
int `int square(int)'::`2'::i DD 05H                        ; `square'::`2'::i
_TLS    ENDS

num$ = 8
int square(int) PROC                                    ; square
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+8], ecx
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:int a      ; a
        mov     eax, eax
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _tls_index
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR gs:88
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rdx+rcx*8]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:int `int square(int)'::`2'::i
        mov     edx, edx
        mov     r8d, DWORD PTR _tls_index
        mov     r9, QWORD PTR gs:88
        mov     r8, QWORD PTR [r9+r8*8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rcx+rax]
        imul    eax, DWORD PTR [r8+rdx]
        ret     0
int square(int) ENDP                                    ; square
```

This loads a 64 bit pointer from `gs:88` (`gs:[0x58]`, which is the linear address of the thread-local storage array), then loads a 64 bit pointer using the `TLS array pointer + _tls_index*8` (this is obviously locating the index in the array * pointer size). `Int a;` is then loaded from this pointer + offset into the .tls segment. Seeing as both variables use the same `_tls_index`, it suggests that there is an index per .exe, i.e. per .tls section, indeed there is one `_tls_index` per TLS directory in `.rdata`, and the variables are packed together at the address pointed to by the TLS array. `static thread_local` variables in different translation units will be merged into .tls and all be packed together at the same index.

I believe that `mainCRTStartup`, which the linker always includes in the final executable and makes it the entry point if it is being linked as a console application, references the `_tls_used` variable (because every .exe needs its own index) and it was pragma'd to go in the T fragment of `.rdata` in whatever object file within `libcmt.lib` defines it (and because `mainCRTStartup` references it the linker will include it in the final executable). If the linker finds a reference to a `_tls_used` variable, it will make sure to include it and make sure the PE header TLS directory points to it.

```
#pragma section(".rdata$T", long, read)    //creates a read only section called `.rdata` if not created and a fragment T in the section
#define _CRTALLOC(x) __declspec(allocate(x))
#pragma data_seg()   //set the compilers current default data section to `.data`

_CRTALLOC(".rdata$T")  //place in the section .rdata, fragment T
const IMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY _tls_used =
{
 (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR) &_tls_start, // start of tls data in the tls section
 (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR) &_tls_end,   // end of tls data
 (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR) &_tls_index, // address of tls_index
 (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR) (&__xl_a+1), // pointer to callbacks
 (ULONG) 0,                      // size of tls zero fill
 (ULONG) 0                       // characteristics
};
```

http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=183

`_tls_used` is a variable of type `IMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY` structure, with the above initialised content, and it's actually defined in `tlssup.c`. Prior to this, it defines `_tls_index`, `_tls_start` and `_tls_end`, placing `_tls_start` at the start of the `.tls` section and `_tls_end` at the end of the `.tls` section by placing it in the section fragment`ZZZ` such that it alphabetically ends up at the end of the section:

```
#pragma data_seg(".tls") //set the compilers current default data section to `.tls`

#if defined (_M_IA64) || defined (_M_AMD64)
_CRTALLOC(".tls")   //place the following in the section named `.tls`
#endif
char _tls_start = 0;   //if not defined, place in the current default data section, which is also `.tls`

#pragma data_seg(".tls$ZZZ")

#if defined (_M_IA64) || defined (_M_AMD64)
_CRTALLOC(".tls$ZZZ")
#endif
char _tls_end = 0;
```

The addresses of these are then used as markers in the `_tls_used` TLS directory. The address will only be resolved by the linker when the `.tls` section is complete and it has a fixed relative `lea` location.

**GCC** (TLS is directly before FS base; raw data rather than pointers)

```
 mov    edx,DWORD PTR fs:0xfffffffffffffff8 //access thread_local int1 inside function
 mov    eax,DWORD PTR fs:0xfffffffffffffffc //access thread_local int2 inside function
```

Making one, both or none of the variables local produces identical code.

When the thread execution terminates, the thread library on windows will deallocate the storage using `TlsFree()` calls (it also must deallocate the memory on the heap pointed to the pointer returned by `TlsGetValue()`).

Answer (score 2):

First note that a block-local thread-local [is implicitly static thread_local](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22794382/783510). In other words, your example code is equivalent to:

```
int main()
{
    static thread_local int n {42};
    std::thread t(My::f, &n);
    t.join();
    std::cout << n << "\n"; // prints 43
    return 0;
}
```

Variables declared with `thread_local` inside a function are not so different from globally defined thread_locals. In both cases, you create an object that is unique per thread and whose lifetime is bound to the lifetime of the thread.

The difference is only that globally defined thread_locals will be initialized [when the new thread is run before you enter any thread-specific functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35508251/783510). In contrast, a block-local thread-local variable is initialized [the first time control passes through its declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794608/783510).

A use case would be to speed up a function by defining a local cache that is reused during the lifetime of the thread:

```
void foo() {
  static thread_local MyCache cache;
  // ...
}
```

(I used `static thread_local` here to make it explicit that the cache will be reused if the function is executed multiple times within the same thread, but it is a matter of taste. If you drop the `static`, it will not make any difference.)

---

A comment about your the example code. Maybe it was intentional,  but the thread is not really accessing the thread_local `n`. Instead it operates on a copy of a pointer, which was created by the thread running `main`. Because of that both threads refer to the same memory.

In other words, a more verbose way would have been:

```
int main()
{
    thread_local int n {42};
    int* n_ = &n;
    std::thread t(My::f, n_);
    t.join();
    std::cout << n << "\n"; // prints 43
    return 0;
}
```

If you change the code, so the thread accesses `n`, it will operate on its own version, and `n` belonging to the main thread will not be modified:

```
int main()
{
    thread_local int n {42};
    std::thread t([&] { My::f(&n); });
    t.join();
    std::cout << n << "\n"; // prints 42 (not 43)
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a more complicated example. It calls the function two times to show that the state is preserved between the calls. Also its output shows that the threads operate on their own state:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void foo() {
  thread_local int n = 1;
  std::cout << "n=" << n << " (main)" << std::endl;
  n = 100;
  std::cout << "n=" << n << " (main)" << std::endl;
  int& n_ = n;
  std::thread t([&] {
          std::cout << "t executing...\n";
          std::cout << "n=" << n << " (thread 1)\n";
          std::cout << "n_=" << n_ << " (thread 1)\n";
          n += 1;
          std::cout << "n=" << n << " (thread 1)\n";
          std::cout << "n_=" << n_ << " (thread 1)\n";
          std::cout << "t executing...DONE" << std::endl;
        });
  t.join();
  std::cout << "n=" << n << " (main, after t.join())\n";
  n = 200;
  std::cout << "n=" << n << " (main)" << std::endl;

  std::thread t2([&] {
          std::cout << "t2 executing...\n";
          std::cout << "n=" << n << " (thread 2)\n";
          std::cout << "n_=" << n_ << " (thread 2)\n";
          n += 1;
          std::cout << "n=" << n << " (thread 2)\n";
          std::cout << "n_=" << n_ << " (thread 2)\n";
          std::cout << "t2 executing...DONE" << std::endl;
        });
  t2.join();
  std::cout << "n=" << n << " (main, after t2.join())" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  foo();
  std::cout << "---\n";
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
n=1 (main)
n=100 (main)
t executing...
n=1 (thread 1)      # the thread used the "n = 1" init code
n_=100 (thread 1)   # the passed reference, not the thread_local
n=2 (thread 1)      # write to the thread_local
n_=100 (thread 1)   # did not change the passed reference
t executing...DONE
n=100 (main, after t.join())
n=200 (main)
t2 executing...
n=1 (thread 2)
n_=200 (thread 2)
n=2 (thread 2)
n_=200 (thread 2)
t2 executing...DONE
n=200 (main, after t2.join())
---
n=200 (main)        # second execution: old state is reused
n=100 (main)
t executing...
n=1 (thread 1)
n_=100 (thread 1)
n=2 (thread 1)
n_=100 (thread 1)
t executing...DONE
n=100 (main, after t.join())
n=200 (main)
t2 executing...
n=1 (thread 2)
n_=200 (thread 2)
n=2 (thread 2)
n_=200 (thread 2)
t2 executing...DONE
n=200 (main, after t2.join())
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the great examples already given by Cruz Jean (I don't think I could add to those), consider also the following: there's no reason to forbid it. I don't think you doubt the usefulness of `thread_local` or question why it should be in the language in general. There is a well-defined meaning for a `thread_local` block-scope variable simply as a result of how storage classes and scopes work in C++. Just because one cannot think of something "interesting" to do with every possible combination of language features doesn't mean that all combinations of language features that don't have at least one known "interesting" application must explicitly be disallowed. By that logic, we'd also have to go ahead and disallow classes with no private members from having friends and whatnot. At least to me, C++ in particular seems to follow a philosophy of "if there's no specific technical reason why feature X cannot work in situation Y, then there's no reason to forbid it", which I would consider a quite healthy approach. Forbidding things for no good reason means adding complexity for no good reason. And I believe everyone would agree that there's already enough complexity in C++. It also prevents happy accidents like when, only after many years, a certain language feature is suddenly discovered to have previously unthought-of applications. The most prominent example of such a case would probably be templates which (at least as far as I'm aware) were not originally conceived with the purpose of metaprogramming in mind; it just turned out later that they could also be used for that…

Comment: This is an interesting point, +1. I had not thought of it in quite this way. Why forbid, indeed? There is already enough complexity, as you say.